# Proof of quadrature formula

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, numerical-methods, numerical-calculus, quadrature

Let *f(x)* be an integrable function in the interval $[a,b]$, and let $x_0, x_1, ..., x_n $ be distinct points in $[a,b]$ (not necessarily uniformly spaced). Integrating the polynomial of degree *n* that interpolates *f(x)* at the points $x_i$, we obtain a quadrature formula of the form $$I_n(f) = \sum_{i=0}^n a_{i}f(x_i)$$ Prove that $ \sum_{i=0}^n a_{i} = b - a$.

---

**Attempt:** I believe that the $a_i$ are the quadrature weights? One can obtain $a_i$ by setting $$a_i = \int_a^b L_i(x)dx $$ and computing the Lagrange polynomials. For example: for $n=1, x_0 = a,$ and $ x_1 = b $: $L_o(x) = \dfrac {x-b}{a-b}$ and $L_1 = \dfrac {x-a}{b-a}$. Then we have the weights $$a_o = \int_a^b \dfrac {x-b}{a-b}dx = \dfrac {b-a}{2}$$ $$a_1 = \int_a^b \dfrac {x-a}{b-a}dx = \dfrac {b-a}{2}$$

Taking the sum for $n = 1$ we get: $$ \sum_{i=0}^1 a_{i} = b - a$$

Is this a correct proof?

Comment: What is $\phi_n$ ?

Comment: I think it represents that Legendre polynomials but I am not sure.

Comment: I don't know how you define quadrature formulas, but I suspect they are supposed to satisfy the equality $\sum_{i=0}^n a_i f\left(x_i\right) = \int_a^b f\left(x\right) dx$ for all polynomials $f$ of sufficiently low degree (maybe $\leq n$). In that case, you get $\sum_{i=0}^n a_i = b-a$ by applying this equality to $f = 1$ (the constant polynomial $1$).

Comment: @darijgrinberg You should post your comment as an answer... It is spot on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As polynomials of degrees up to $n$ are interpolated exactly, you know from interpolating $p(x)=1$ that
$$
1=\sum_{k=0}^nL_k(x)~\text{ for all }x\in\Bbb R.
$$
Now integrate this over $[a,b]$.